# JS, how to stop process execution if it's beeing executed ...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I stop sending data to the server if the button allready has been clicked ? I don't want a disable="disabled" response (buttons are custom made).

I tried setting a global `var button_clicked = FALSE;` set it true when button has been clicked, after that set it again to false when the response has been received . But that doesnt work neither because my mouse is messed up and spam clicks really fast (although i click only once -> this actualy helped me to see that the method mentioned isn't so acurate).

Are there better methods to stop a process or disable a DOM element onClick? Maybe disable the event? js or jquery answer preferable . Or maybe this really can't be done on really fast requests . I know it depends on alot of things (like user's cpu). Any comment or answer is welcome. Maybe for every click on the page set the user to wait for some miliseconds ?

Comment: so what is this button? is this part of an AJAX request? is this a submit button of a form? can you specify?

Comment: like i said it's a custom button (not using buton ur submit tags) , yes it's for ajax request .

Comment: Your computer would most likely be faster than your click speed. Can you show us the code used? A flag should be fine for what you need.

Comment: confused by the post. you ask  *"How can I stop sending data to the server if the button allready has been clicked ?"* and then later, *"Are there better methods to stop a process or disable a DOM element onClick?"*. which is it? do you want to abort an AJAX request or do you want to disable a click when a request is ongoing?

Comment: it's simple. first click the button, then run to the outlet and unplug the computer before it finishes processing.

Comment: @Joseph it's the most common problem ... form duplication . Since i'm talking about js / DOM / buttons / requests , yes it's about the process of sending data to server asyncronously with ajax , after a user clicks a button. I want to stop the duplication problem ...

Comment: @CataCata use my answer. It'll stop multiple submits, and allow you to unblock another submit on callback if you want it to. :)

Comment: then you can at least simplify your post so that it can help future askers. you never mentioned in your post that it was about AJAX nor preventing a spammed request. your question is the typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/177538)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this little constructor:

```
function MyForm()
{
  this.check = false;

  this.form = function(){
    var f = this;
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault
      if( f.check === false )
      {
        f.check = true;
        $.ajax({
          ...blah blah
          success: function( data )
          {
            //if you want to let them send again, uncomment this next line
            //f.check = false;
          }
        })
      }
  });
  this.form();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var my = new MyForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you register an event listener, the Event object you get will have a [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) method. This avoids following a clicked link or sending a submitted form.

If it is a custom action triggered by an event handler, the only possibility is to check a condition in the handler function whether the action really should be taken. Yet, a disabled button is not that bad because you will need to inform the user that nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the click handler when the button is clicked. Add it again when you are ready for the next click.

```
button.onclick = null;
```